# Update the row in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I'm stuck on a question please help me out. Let me explain the question
Let's assume a table has a limit of 10 rows. and when we want to add the 11th row it should replace the data of the 1st row.
I'm thinking the logic should be like this: if id > 10 then it will replace by ( id % 10 ) place. But don't what will be the query in PSQL.
Please help me out. Thanks in advance:slightly_smiling_face:

I want a master nodejs server and 5 slave servers. and the slave servers have their own DB. The master node doesn't have any DB. That server only can take data from users and distribute it among the slave server. And Each Slave server's capacity is 10. They can store 10 data and when 50data is stored among them then the 51st data will replace 1st data.

Comment: Please describe more precise what you would like to do. Are you going to do an update or an insert? Where should this happen? Are you receiving one row only or more? What should happen for id 12,13,14...?

Comment: Create 10 (empty) records and REVOKE everybody from inserting new records. Now you're 100% sure you will only have 10 records. Just UPDATE these records and you're fine.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data. Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: [Why](https://xyproblem.info/) does the table have a 10 row limit?

Comment: I want a master nodejs server and 5 slave servers. and the slave servers have their own DB. The master node doesn't have any DB. That server only can take data from users and distribute it among the slave server. 

And Each Slave server's capacity is 10. They can store 10 data and when 50data is stored among them then the 51st data will replace 1st data.